# Taking Information from a Datasheet subform into another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm creating a database to help log some inspections i recently done then breaking down any maintenance issues to log into a different table (tbl_Activity_Maint)

i'm using a Form with a sub form in Datasheet view (source Tbl_Blank_Inspections) . I want to take the data in the datasheet and move it into a different table then delete the source entry by clicking the "Add maintenance' button at the bottom.
[Scrren shot of entry forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffCqi.jpg)

but my code isnt working... can you help?

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Activity_Maint (A_Maint_Problem, A_Maint_Follow_Up, A_Maint_Date_Identified)
SELECT BLI_Maint_Problem, BLI_Maint_Follow_Up, BLI_Maint_Date_Identified
FROM Tbl_Blank_Inspections
WHERE <condition>;
```

Comment: [ask] : *isnt working* is not a useful problem description. Also please show the full SQL.

Comment: Fair call, that is the full SQL.. i have attached it to a button:

Private Sub Command40_Click()


INSERT INTO tbl_Activity_Maint (A_Maint_Problem, A_Maint_Follow_Up, A_Maint_Date_Identified)
SELECT BLI_Maint_Problem, BLI_Maint_Follow_Up, BLI_Maint_Date_Identified
FROM Tbl_Blank_Inspections
WHERE <condition>;


End Sub


it comes up with a Compile Error:
                               Expected: Case